# ADO YAML Templates - how to handle small number of platform-dependent tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, cross-platform, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am in the process of porting some existing Classic ADO pipelines to YAML. There are two separate Classic pipelines for Windows and Linux, but, because I have been able to switch most scripting to `bash`, I am close to having a common cross-platform YAML pipeline.

Nevertheless, I still have a few platform-dependent tasks interspersed between the majority platform-independent tasks. Of these few tasks, some only need to run on Windows and don't exist for Linux, and the remainder exist in two platform-specific versions of the tasks - one using bash and the other batch or PowerShell.

My hope was to make the bulk of the script into a template with an `isWindows` parameter, and to use this parameters to control the platform-dependent parts. This is roughly what I have, but it is not working:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: BuildPool
  demands:
  - Agent.OS -equals Windows_NT

extends:
  template: common-template.yml
  parameters:
    isWindows: true
```

Then `common-template.yml` itself. Note that the approach here, using `condition`, does not work. Although I have omitted most of the cross-platform tasks, these form the majority of the pipeline - there are only a few tasks that need special handling.

```
parameters:
- name: isWindows
  type: boolean

jobs:
- job: MyJob

  steps:
  - checkout: none
    clean: true

  # Simple example of cross-platform script task
  - bash: |
      env
    displayName: Print Environment

  # ... more cross platform tasks

  # Windows only task
  - task: CmdLine@2
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.isWindows }}', 'true')
    inputs:
      filename: scripts\windows_only.bat

  # ... more cross platform tasks

  # Task with specialization for each platform
  # WINDOWS version
  - task: CmdLine@2
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.isWindows }}', 'true')
    inputs:
      filename: scripts\task_a.bat
  # LINUX version
  - task: Bash@3
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.isWindows }}', 'false')
    inputs:
      filePath: scripts/task_a.sh

  # ... more cross platform tasks
```

The issue is that when I try to run with a Linux agent I get this error:

`No agent found in pool <pool name> satisfies both of the following demands: Agent.OS, Cmd. All demands: Agent.OS -equals Linux, Cmd, Agent.Version ...`

I assume this is because `CmdLine` tasks are present, even though they are "turned off" via a `condition`. I assume the dependency on the task is probably determined before the condition is ever evaluated.

Is what I am trying to do possible? Is there another approach? I am not very experienced with ADO and this is the first time I have tried anything with templates so I am possibly missing something straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PowerShell steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-powershell?view=azure-pipelines) instead of batch/bash (PowerShell can be installed on both Windows and Linux).

You can also remove the demands and just use the [predefined `Agent.OS` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services) in your conditions for tasks which require specific OS:

```yaml
- powershell: 'scripts/windows_only.ps1'
  condition: eq(variables['Agent.OS', 'Windows_NT')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, for various reasons, bash is much preferred (not just by me) for cross-platform scripting. Also, I would rather avoid any config changes to build agents for the time being. Basically, we do have a definite requirement for the flexibility to choose platform-appropriate scripting languages. I believe I have solved the issue now and will post my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the ADO docs a bit, I discovered that what I needed was called Conditional Insertion:

```
parameters:
- name: isWindows
  type: boolean

jobs:
- job: MyJob

  ...

  # Windows only task
  - ${{ if parameters.isWindows }}:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        filename: scripts\windows_only.bat

  # Task with specialization for each platform
  - ${{ if parameters.isWindows }}:
    # WINDOWS version
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        filename: scripts\task_a.bat
  - $ {{ else }}:
    # LINUX version
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        filePath: scripts/task_a.sh

  ...
```

There were a few tricky things that might be worth highlighting:

1. The "conditions" act as items in the YAML list of tasks. Hence there is a need to prefix with `-` .
2. The actual task that is protected by the condition is then indented a further level with respect to the condition line.
3. Don't forget the colon at the end of the condition.
4. The syntax I showed above doesn't actually work for me - I got an error about using `else`. It turned out that the *else* syntax is a feature of the 2022 release of ADO and we are stuck on the 2020 release. So in my case I had to introduce inverted tests: `${{ if not(parameters.isWindows) }}:`
5. I got quite confused about how to test for true values. Various examples in the documentation, when talking about expressions in the `condition` field of a task, use syntax like: `condition: eq(variables.isSomeCondition, 'true')`. Note the comparison against a string value. I initially copied this in the inclusion expressions but found that both `${{ if eq(parameters.isWindows, 'true') }}:` and `${{ if eq(parameters.isWindows, 'false') }}:` triggered when the parameter itself was `true`. Clearly, the strings `'true'` and `'false'` evaluate to a boolean `true` in this context. It's not that this doesn't make sense - it is the inconsistency with the documented examples of the `condition` syntax that caught me out.